# How do I find g(x) given the stationary points (2,9)?

Tags: functions, derivatives, cubics, stationary-point

[question image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ew8U.jpg)

given the info I form the equation g(x) = AX³+BX²+AX+C and did g'(x) = 0 to find B = -13A/4 (when x = 2). So using B and putting it into g(x) = 9, I get AX³-13A/4X²+AX+C = 9 and I am confused on how to find the values for A, B and C...

Comment: It passes through the origin $(0,0),$ so as you have it written, $0=g(0)=A\cdot0^3+B\cdot0^2+A\cdot0+C.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following from your solving for B, we have the expression
$$g(x)=Ax^3-\frac{13A}{4}x^2+Ax+C.$$
Since $g$ passes through the origin we have $$0=A\cdot0^3-\frac{13A}{4}\cdot0^2+A\cdot0+C.$$
giving $C = 0$.
So far it reduces to
$$g(x)=Ax^3-\frac{13A}{4}x^2+Ax.$$
Since $g$ passes through $(2,9)$ we have $$9=A\cdot2^3-\frac{13A}{4}\cdot2^2+A\cdot2= 8A-13A+2A = -3A.$$
Solving for $A$ and $B$ gives $A=-3$ thus $B=\frac{-3\cdot 13}{4}=-39/4.$
Finally $$g(x)=-3x^3-\frac{39}{4}x^2-3x.$$